# QMYSQL Driver not loaded using Qt 5.12.0 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

Hi I'm trying to build a program that connect on MySQL, i have this error 
**"QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7"**

But i already **"libmysqlclient.so.20"** and **"libqsqlmysql.so"** in my sqldrivers folder. Please do help me, I'm a beginner in QT Programming. Sorry for my grammar.

I'm using this code

```
      QSqlDatabase db1 = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase( "QMYSQL" );
      db1.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
      db1.setPort(8080);
      db1.setDatabaseName( "sample" );
      db1.setUserName( "root" );
      db1.setPassword( "" );

      if( !db1.open() )
      {
          qDebug() << db1.lastError();
          qFatal( "Failed to connect." );
       }
           qDebug( "Connected!" );
```

Comment: Do you have `libqt4-sql-mysql` installed? If so, why do you need the folder `sqldrivers`? It seems that these libraries might have different version.

Comment: I have no libqt4-sql-mysql install , what should i do? Thank you for helping

Comment: Install it and move the folder `sqldrivers` somewhere, then try to compile and launch your program.

Comment: libqt4-sql-mysql won’t help for Qt 5.12.0, other than it might install the right libmysqlclient (or whatever its called exactly) dependencies. Copying the libmysqlclient to sqldrivers won’t help, as the system won’t look there I think, unless you set LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I would suggest to install libmysqlclient via apt.